# Is there a better way to switch between 2 different styles than this using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 function dropDown(controller) {
        controller.toggle ? controller.content.style = "display: none;" : controller.content.style = "display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr;";
        controller.toggle = !controller.toggle;
    }
```

This is what some of my code looks like right now for a project that I am doing and it feels inefficient using a variable to toggle between 2 states. I tried thinking of a way to use classList.toggle("class"); but it can't toggle between 2 different styles, it just toggles one on and off.

Comment: Instead of using style=display:none maybe using a css-class like "hide" is that thing you desire.
In newer browsers you can use the ``element.classList.toggle("hide")`` method on any DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

First put the styles in `CSS` classes:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.someClass {
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

Then apply `someClass` to the element and use `toggle` method from `classList` object to toggle hidden class:

```
controller.classList.toggle('hidden');
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

If you can use `jQuery`, it's very simple:

```
$(controller).toggleClass("someClass hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two classes in css containing each style and then toggle between them :

**CSS :**

.X 
{

// having one style

}

.Y
{

//having other style
}

**.js**

```
$('#div').toggleClass('X Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `hide` class initially on your element, then you can remove the class and add another after a condition.

Try this:

```js
function dropDown(controller) {
  if (controller.content.classList.contains('hide')) {
    controller.content.classList.remove('hide');
    controller.content.classList.add('showGrid');
  } else {
    controller.content.classList.add('hide');
    controller.content.classList.remove('showGrid');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.showGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a ternary seems to be the right approach, however it can be simplified a lot:

```
 const {content, toggle} = controller;
 content.style = (toggle = ! toggle) ? "display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr;" : "display: none;";
```

Comment: What is that notation called for the 
const {content, toggle} = controller;

Comment: @ammawn object destructuring